# Editing Channel Permissions with Eris

Tags: javascript, discord, eris

Heyo, I'm working on a ticket system (;ticket), I've gotten down all the creation code so far. And now I just can't figure out how to edit channel permissions so the user can see the channel.

I've tried Discord.js's version (as they're often somewhat similar), and no luck.

On the Eris wiki, this is what the form is:

[image]

I have tried `bot.editChannelPermission('610969665744666664','245569534218469376' -)` that's all I know what to fill in for. Let me know if you guys know. I've asked around to large Eris developers, and they don't know either.
*I am writing in Eris*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I've figured it out.

`msg.channel..editPermission('user/role id','permnumallow','permnumdeny','member/roe','Reason'))`

Permission numbers can be found here: https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#0

Answer (score 0):

You can update the channel permissions by typing

```js
channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
    id: message.guild.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
  },
  {
    id: "OTHER ID"
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
  }
])
```

-Detektiv Alex

Comment: `msg.channel.overwritePermissions is not a function`